# Develop a task-specific web browser

Tags: browser, browser-extension

I want to build a task-specific web browser. For example, when the user uses that browser, the program should give options like these:

> What is your interest today? Please select from the following:
>
> - computer science
> - data science
> - web development
> - psychology
> - biology
> - social media
> - etc.

After the user selects their interest, the browser should allow the user to search or study only those selected content types, so the user cannot get diverted from their task. The purpose of this browser is to avoid time-wasting. Because whenever someone tries to study or do some professional work, they get diverted by opening social media tabs and movies.

Which programming language will be suitable for making this browser?

Comment: any attempt to solve the problem?

Comment: Not for real...i search for this but didn't get any path..i am still confuse

Comment: See https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3

Comment: What is this policy list?

Comment: @Abbas _"I want to build a task specific web browser"_ You can build a custom version of chromium browser, see https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code

Comment: Oh!great now it make sense to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do this by making a custom version of an existing browser, as [guest271314 suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2801559/guest271314), but that would require far more effort than necessary. All you need to make is a browser extension, such as a [Firefox Add-on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons) or a [Chrome Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted). Browser extensions are usually written with JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. Each browser needs to have an extension made individually, but you can usually share a lot of the code between them. Read the linked documentation for help creating an extension for each browser.

There are already existing browser extensions like you describe that prevent you from visiting sites that you put on a list ahead of time, such as [StayFocusd](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stayfocusd/laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji?hl=en) and [WasteNoTime](http://www.bumblebeesystems.com/wastenotime/). Maybe you just want to use one of those extensions instead of writing a new one.